# For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $\max(x, y) = \frac{x + y + |x - y|}{2},$ and $\min(x, y) = \frac{x + y - |x - y|}{2}$.

Tags: maxima-minima

Prove that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, 
$$\max(x, y) = \dfrac{x + y + |x - y|}{2},$$
and 
$$\min(x, y) = \dfrac{x + y - |x - y|}{2}.$$
For any real number $x$, the **absolute value** of $x$, denoted $|x|$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
|x| = \begin{cases} x; & \text{ if } x \geq 0 \\
-x; & \text{ if } x< 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

What I understand from this is that $|x| = x$ if $x \geq 0$ or $|x| = −x$ if $x<0$. Other than that I don't really know how to start this.

Comment: Too cumbersome to read a question post that way. Write the question down...and you're asking whether to know the definition of the absolute value function is to be on the right way to solve the question? Well...yes, but that doesn't seem to be a lot

Comment: Here is a guide to formatting with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Take two cases . . . Case (1): $x\ge y$. Case (2): $x<y$. In each case, you know which of $x,y$ is min and which is max. Also, in each case, you can simplify the absolute value expression.

Comment: Why is this discrete mathematics?

Comment: Technically, it's enough to consider @quasi's case (1), since both equalities are symmetric in $\,x,y\,$.

Comment: @NashJ. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   \max\{x,y\} + \min\{x,y\} &= x + y \\
   \max\{x,y\} - \min\{x,y\} &=  |x-y| \\ 
\text{Adding we get} \\
2\max\{x,y\} &= x + y + |x-y| \\
\text{Subtracting we get} \\
2\min\{x,y\} &= x + y - |x-y| \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This is a good approach, but it might be useful to rewrite $|x-y|$ in terms of $x$ and $y$:
$$
|x-y|=\left\{\begin{array}{}
x-y&\text{if }x\ge y\\
y-x&\text{if }x\lt y
\end{array}\right.
$$
Using this in your formula should make things simpler.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-y|$ means the distance between $x$ and $y$ in the number line.

On the other hand, $\frac{x+y}{2}$ means the midpoint between $x$ and $y$.

(you can check those two statements if you didn't know them!)

Therefore, $\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}=\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{|x-y|}{2}$, which means adding *half the distance between $x$ and $y$*  to the midpoint of $x$ and $y$, is $\max(x, y)$.

Similarly, $\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}=\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{|x-y|}{2}$, which means subtracting *half the distance between $x$ and $y$*  from the midpoint of $x$ and $y$, is $\min(x, y)$.

Answer (score 0):

> **If** $\displaystyle x>y$ **then** $x-y>0$:

$|x-y|=x-y$

$\max(x,y) = (x+y+x−y)/2 = x$

$\min(x,y) =  (x+y-(x−y))/2 = y$

> **If** $\displaystyle x<y$ **then** $x-y<0$:

$|x-y|=y-x$

$\max(x,y) = (x+y+y-x)/2 = y$

$\min(x,y) =  (x+y-(y-x))/2 = x$

> **If** $x=y$ **then**:

$|x-y|=0$

$\max(x,y) = (x+y)/2 = x=y$

$\min(x,y) =  (x+y)/2 =x=y$

Comment: Wow thank you so you basically used a direct proof  and cases to prove all of that? And I have a question/answer on why the reason max(x,y)=(x+y+y−x)/2=y is it becuase the x's cancel out and which is why you said it is equal to y right?

Comment: You are welcome, Preston. Yes, there are 3 general cases for a number: to be bigger, smaller or equal to another number. About your last question: Yes, that's right. @PrestonGarvey